# Yii Framework - from url to route

Tags: yii

I searched, but couldnt find something.
So, I have route rules:

```php
...

'/reg' => '/user/user/registration',
...
```

in

```php
Yii::app()->request
```

I couldn find any route information.

So, how can I get in module init function and having only url, route lile

```
/reg -> user/user/registration
```

**UPD**

Comment: Show all routes: them depends on their order.

Comment: This is wrong answer. the only way i found to do this is to override getPathInfo(), getRequestUri(), protected $_requestUri; and $_pathInfo; in child class: 

```
class HttpRequest extends CHttpRequest
{
 protected $_requestUri;
 protected $_pathInfo; 

 public function setUri($uri){
  $this->_requestUri = $uri;
 }

 public function setPathInfo($route){
  $this->_pathInfo = $route;
 }

 public function getPathInfo(){ /* copy from parent */ }

 public function getRequestUri(){ /* copy from parent */ }

```

Comment: can you explain your answer in "answer question" mode @alexglue?

Comment: sure, @Miroff, done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today (next day after my question), I could solve this.

I will try to explain:

As Michael wrote, we cant know in module in which controller we are.

But I net get just reversed route, so, its quite esay.

```
Yii::app()->getUrlManager()->parseUrl('/reg');
```

This will return my reversed route

```
user/user/registration
```

[parseUrl](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CBaseUrlRule#parseUrl-detail)

Answer (score 0):

The route is only available from the running controller. By the time when a module is initialized the controller is not yet available, thus you can't find out the route there. (You can follow [CWebApplication::processRequest](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebApplication#processRequest-detail) to see what happens when a request is resolved up to the point where the controller is run.)

It depends on what you try to achieve, but you could override [WebModule::beforeControllerAction](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebModule#beforeControllerAction-detail) to do something before the module controller is run.

Comment: Why don't you share your wisdom with us? :)

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new on stackoverflow, I don't know how to do that. Can you explain?

Comment: You said, you found the answer. You should tell us, what you found. If my answer was helpful, you could accept it as right answer or upvote it. If not, you could add a comment to your question and explain, what you found out or how you solved it. You could also edit your question and add a note on the bottom, how you solve id.

Comment: all after line "Today (next day after my question), I could solve this." are my solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

*Solution for Yii 1.1.15* workes for me.

```
class HttpRequest extends CHttpRequest {

    protected $_requestUri;
    protected $_pathInfo;

    public function setUri($uri){
        $this->_requestUri = $uri;
    }

    public function setPathInfo($route){
        $this->_pathInfo = $route;
    }

    public function getPathInfo(){
        /* copy from parent */ 
    }

    public function getRequestUri(){
        /* copy from parent */ 
    }
}
```

The usage:

```
    $uri_path = 'my/project-alias/wall';

    /** @var HttpRequest $request */
    $request = clone Yii::app()->getRequest();
    $request->setUri($uri_path);
    $request->setPathInfo(null);

    $route = Yii::app()->getUrlManager()->parseUrl($request);

    //$route equals 'project/profile/wall' etc here (like in route rules);
```

Comment: I think, this solution is more harder. Why you didnt like that solution which I found? (it works fine)

Comment: @Miroff cause it does not works on Yii 1.1.5: i got "Fatal error: Call to a member function getPathInfo() on a non-object in /vendor/yiisoft/yii/framework/web/CUrlManager.php on line 364" on string ```$rawPathInfo=$request->getPathInfo();``` because $request should be an object having protected $pathInfo etc by design.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a slightly different sub-class of CHttpRequest:

```
class CustomHttpRequest extends \CHttpRequest
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    var $pathInfo;
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $method;

    public function __construct($pathInfo, $method)
    {
        $this->pathInfo = $pathInfo;
        $this->method = $method;
    }

    public function getPathInfo()
    {
        return $this->pathInfo; // Return our path info rather than the default
    }

    public function getRequestType()
    {
        return $this->method;
    }
}
```

Then to call it (to create a controller, which is what I want):

```
$request = new CustomHttpRequest($uri, $method); // e.g. 'my/project-alias/wall' and 'GET'
$route = \Yii::app()->getUrlManager()->parseUrl($request);
list($jcontroller, $actionName) = \Yii::app()->createController($route);
```

Comment: this solution for yii2?